# sharepoint audience Not compiling new users from ad

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, active-directory, audiences

I have 7 people in total in one of my Active Directory groups. 4 of them is created before May this year and 3 after.

When I run a full user profile sync, and after that compile the audience for that AD group, I only get the 4 people that are created before May.

If I remove one user that was created before May, and run the sync and compile again, it says I have 3 people in the audience group.

Do anyone have any idea why some of the users do not get synced?

All users are not disabled. All have been logged into our SharePoint site.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  Some questions to see if we are in the same boat:
1. Can you get the broken users to show up if you use a property based rule?   (For example "Account Name = domain\joe.smith" instead of "User member Of All Users")  I can.

2. Can you get the user to show up in an audience using a different AD group that they are a member of?  I can't.

3.  Can you use that AD group to grant them permission to a site/list in SharePoint?  I can.